# Include a class as member variable in another class (C++)

Tags: c++, include, binary-search-tree, aggregation

I am trying to create a binary search tree of Player objects.  I have previously defined the Player class.  However, when I go to include the player object in the structure for each node of the BST, I get an error that Player is undefined even though I thought I had set up the includes properly.Is there any way for me to go about this without having to rethink my implementation?

I simplified the code a little to demonstrate:

BST header:

```
class Player;
class BinarySearchTree{
private:

    struct  Node  {
        Player info;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };

    Node *root;
    void Insert(Node*& tree, Player p);
    void PrintTree(Node* tree, std::ostream& out);
```

};

BST.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
//all methods implemented afterwards
```

Player.h

```
class Player{

private:
    std::string* name = new std::string;
    int* score = new int;

public:
 //....
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
//...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler needs to see the definition of `class Player` in header file (BST.h) which you have provided in BST.cpp ( by including "Player.h").

So, BST header should be:-

```
#include "Player.h"         <<<include this file

class Player;               <<<remove this forward declaration
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:

    struct  Node  {
        Player info;
```

Comment: Ah I had read somewhere that you shouldn't include in the headers like that but I guess I must have misread.  Seems to work fine now thanks!

Comment: If your class had held a pointer rather than an object then your forward declaration work have worked fine, and when you can avoid including in a header it's worth doing so. But in order to define the layout/size of the object (as the declaration does) then it has do know the contents of any objects that make it up.

Comment: Ah because declaring as a pointer it doesn't need to know the size of the Player class, it only needs to know it has to store a pointer.  That makes so much sense and its really clear now thanks so much!!